# how to download Excel in CF from a query

Tags: html, coldfusion

I have a simple form which displays cfquery data in a `<table>`. I want to have a button which will download that data into an Excel file. I tried using `cfcontent`, but it is not working. Can anyone help me in this? My form looks like this:

[image: STM]

I just want the tabular data to be downloaded into Excel by clicking a button.

```
<cfcontent type="application/x-msexcel; charset=utf-8" reset="Yes">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#xlsFilenamePartial#">

<table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="tabSiteData">        
                    <thead>                     
                            <cfoutput>                  
                                <span  class = "headerDesc">#objTranslator.Translate("##topbar##",variables.topBarText)#<br></span>
                                <span class = "extrasmalltextbold">Report Generated: #dateformat(now(),"d-mmm-yyyy")# #timeformat(now(),"long")#<br></span>
                                <b>Organization:</b> #form.reportOrg#<br>
                                <b>Suborg:</b> #form.reportsuborg#<br>
                                <b>Site:</b> #form.reportsite#<br>
                                <b>Custom Group:</b>#form.REPORTCUSTOMGROUP#<br><br>    
                            </cfoutput> 
                                 <input type="submit" name="doit" value="Create Excel File">
                            <CFIF #FORM.SiteIDList# NEQ "">
                                    <cfoutput>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Organization/Site</th>
                                            <th>SubOrg</th>
                                            <th>Site Country</th>
                                            <th>site Region</th>
                                            <th>site Lead</th>
                                            <th>Manager</th>
                                            <th>Operation Manager</th>
                                            <th>Compliance Manager</th>
                                            <th>No. of active #CenterDeptLabel#</th>
                                            <th>Site Status</th>
                                            <th>Site address</th>                                                   
                                        </tr>
                                    </cfoutput> 
                    </thead>

                                    <cfoutput query="variables.qryAllSite" group="orgname">                         
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="10" class="orgRow" onclick="rowExpander('#url.year#_#variables.qryAllSite.org#')" style="cursor:pointer;">                         
                                                    <img src="#request.domainProtocol##request.domainurl##request.library.images.url#icons/12x12/
                                                        <cfif url.expandAll>#objTranslator.JSTranslate("collapse.png")#
                                                        <cfelse>#objTranslator.JSTranslate("expand.png")#
                                                        </cfif>" 
                                                        title="<cfif url.expandAll>Collapse<cfelse>Expand</cfif>" 
                                                        id="img_#url.year#_#variables.qryAllSite.org#" 
                                                        name="img_#url.year#_#variables.qryAllSite.org#" expanded="#url.expandAll#">
                                                    #variables.qryAllSite.orgname#
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="bodydata_#url.year#_#variables.qryAllSite.org#" name="bodydata_#url.year#_#variables.qryAllSite.org#" 
                                        <cfif not url.expandAll>style="display:none;"</cfif>>

                                            <cfoutput>              
                                                <cfif #variables.qryAllSite.Archive# IS 0 OR #variables.qryAllSite.Archive# IS "">          
                                                    <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='##d7f5d9';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='';">

                                                        <td class="fullborder" style="padding-left:20px;">#variables.qryAllSite.location# </td>
                                                        <td class="fullborder">
                                                            <cfif #variables.qryAllSite.suborg# IS "">
                                                                -
                                                            <cfelse>
                                                                #variables.qryAllSite.suborg#
                                                            </cfif> 
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="fullborder">
                                                            #variables.qryAllSite.sitecountry#
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="fullborder">
                                                            #variables.qryAllSite.siteregion#
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="fullborder">
                                                            <cfif #variables.qryAllSite.sitelead# IS "">
                                                                -
                                                            <cfelse>    
                                                                #variables.qryAllSite.sitelead#
                                                            </cfif> 
                                                        </td>

                                                        <td class="fullborder">
                                                            <cfif #variables.qryAllSite.manager# IS "">
                                                                -
                                                            <cfelse>    
                                                                #variables.qryAllSite.manager#
                                                            </cfif> 
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="fullborder">
                                                            <cfif #variables.qryAllSite.ops_manager# IS "">
                                                                -
                                                            <cfelse>    
                                                                #variables.qryAllSite.ops_manager#
                                                            </cfif> 
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="fullborder">
                                                            <cfif #variables.qryAllSite.compliance_manager# IS "">
                                                                -
                                                            <cfelse>    
                                                                #variables.qryAllSite.compliance_manager#
                                                            </cfif> 
                                                        </td>

                                                        <td class="fullborder">
                                                                #variables.qryAllSite.DEPT#
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="fullborder fullrightborder">                         
                                                                #variables.qryAllSite.Status#                           
                                                        </td>

                                                    </tr>
                                                </cfif> 
                                            </cfoutput>         
                                        </tbody>
                                    </cfoutput>
                            <CFELSE>
                                <cfoutput>
                                    <span class="noRecordText">No records found for <b>#Form.REPORTCUSTOMGROUP#</b> group</span>                    
                                </cfoutput>
                            </CFIF> 
                    </table>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not working"? What happens when you run the code? Side note - obviously the above does not create a "true" Excel file. Just HTML that most versions of MS Excel can interpret. To generate a real Excel file, you need to use something like `cfspreadsheet`, as mentioned below.

Comment: Also, did you look at similar questions [like this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/05/08/office-2007-open-xml-mime-types.aspx)? Note the different mime type and absence of `<form>` elements in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to try for a lot of code reuse without dealing with cfspreadsheet, you could take all of your code that generates the tables and make that a separate cfm that you can include in your display logic.

Doing that, then you could wire your download as excel button basically wire to a page that is simply

```
<cfsavecontent variable="excelDoc"><cfinclude template="excelGuts.cfm"></cfsavecontent>
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="filename=hackExcel.xls">
<cfcontent type="application/mxexcel" reset="yes" variable="#ToBinary(ToBase64(excelDoc))#"  >
```

You may need the base64 conversion or not, I needed it for doing the same with making a word document via html document joining.

Edit:  Sorry, I just re-read your code and realized you've got it mostly.  I don't believe you can use cfoutput following the content/header change.  I've heard some people get success on it, but everything I've found is that it doesn't work well if you don't have everything after cfcontent on a single line.  So the easiest solution is to save everything into a var using cfsavecontent and dump it into the file contents via the variable attribute in cfcontent.